# Watson VisualRecognition can't classify image, give error 400 (using swift)

Tags: swift, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I am learning to use the VisualRecognition service of Watson. The app send an image to Watson, and then receive the classification result from Watson. It was working properly before. However it suddenly stop working today.

```
let apiKey = "my api key"
let version = "2019-01-01"


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        self.cameraButton.isEnabled = false
        self.folderButton.isEnabled = false
        self.ShareButton.isHidden = true
        foodNameIndicatorText.isHidden = true
        foodDescriptionButtonA.isHidden = true
        foodDescriptionButtonB.isHidden = true
        foodDescriptionButtonC.isHidden = true
        //clear the results array everytime users pick an new image
        self.classificationResults = []
        self.foodItemResults = []
        imageView.image = image
        //dismiss the imgPickerController after presented
        imgPickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        let visualRecognition = VisualRecognition(version: version, apiKey: apiKey)
        visualRecognition.classify(image: image, threshold: 0.0, owners: ["default"], classifierIDs: ["food"], acceptLanguage: "en") { response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("============================here is error =========================================")
                print(error)
                print("============================end of error =========================================")
            }
            guard let classifiedImages = response?.result else {
                print("Failed to classify the image")
                return
            }
            print(classifiedImages) ......
```

ERROR:

```
http(statusCode: Optional(400), message: nil, metadata: nil)
```

============================end of error ==================================

I try to create a new visualRecognition instance, and use its classify method according to Watson's document for IOS. The image parameter I use is from a imagePickerController, where I allow user to pick an image from library. However, I receive an error in the response handler, and the code fail to classify my image. What actually happened?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Lite (free) plan and it suddenly stopped working, my first guess is that you have used the 1000 free events per month that are given for training and / or classification.  Otherwise you should probably open an IBM Cloud customer support ticket with the details of your account instance.

Answer (score 0):

The current interface version of Watson Visual Recognition is `2018-03-19` but you have `2019-01-01` in your code.